# Why wont this SVN Connect Mac (Cornerstone Client)

Tags: svn, version-control, version

[image: img1]

My svn repo details:

- Repository DIR: /home/pricedwr/siterepo/trunk
- joe = myrealpasshere
- Port: 3691

keep getting this error:

[image: img2]

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https:// instead of svn:// ?

Use the HTTPS tab instead of SVN tab.